# Is there a way to insert a row with no data

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Using CakePHP 3.3, I have a table that only contains a primary key. This is used as a sequence. In CakePHP, I insert a row with no data and it generates a new row.

Cake 2.7

```
class Identity extends AppModel {

    function nextVal() {
        $data = [];
        $this->create();
        $this->save($data);
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

I am attempting to duplicate this behavior in CakePHP 3.3 and it isn't doing what I expect.

CakePHP 3.3

```
class IdentityTable extends Table
{
    public function generate() {
        $identity = $this->newEntity();
        if ( $this->save($identity) ) {
            // The $ccn entity contains the id now
            \Cake\Log\Log::debug(__METHOD__. ' success');
            return $identity->id;
        }
        \Cake\Log\Log::debug(__METHOD__. ' failed');
        return false;
    }
    //
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('identity');
        $this->displayField('identityId');
        $this->primaryKey('identityId');
    }
}
```

MySQL is perfectly happy with this:

```
INSERT INTO `identity` () VALUES()
```

I am thinking that the CakePHP 3.x ORM sees that I am not inserting anything and it bailing on the save.

Is there a way in CakePHP 3 to insert a row with no data?

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell cake that something is cahenged in the entity and mark it as 'dirty'. i.e.

```
$identity ->dirty('id', true);
```

so the resulting query will be

```
INSERT INTO sic_suppliers (id) VALUES (NULL)
```

that I guess is ok for you

PS
don't know if this is the best way to achieve this but it seems to work.

**Edit**: following @ndm suggestion you can also insert the record directly (see the [**cookbook**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#inserting-data))

```
$this->query()->insert(['id'])
    ->values([null])
    ->execute();
```

Comment: It may work, given that there are no application rules that would fail for such an empty entity, ie it might be necessary to set `checkRules` to `false`. Another option might be to **[insert the record directly](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#inserting-data)**

Comment: @ndm, but it seems you can't pass an empty array to the insert method, so in a way or another you have to tell cake that one of the fields is null. Anyway I'll edit my answer following your suggestion.

Comment: @ndm also how you can retrieve the id of the inserted entity?

Comment: That is correct, you have to pass at least one field, and passing `null` for the primary key should work fine IIRC. The insert ID can be retrieved via the **[`lastInsertId()`](http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Database.StatementInterface.html#_lastInsertId)** method on the statement object returned by `execute()`. However, this is way more work than saving an empty entity, I've just mentioned it for the sake of completeness ;)